# Site is loading (slowly) and pingdom shows 503 error

Tags: loading-time, speed

I've got my site running onnline at https://bartlett100.com/

(Holding page only unless logged in as super admin)

The site loads, but the initial page load is very slow. it's just the initial doument request, the rest of the assetts load fine after this.

[image]

Also, speed tests like Pingdom return a 503 error, even though the site does load.

https://tools.pingdom.com/#5a2676fdcfc00000

Could this be causing the slow loading. Could it be a problem with the .htaccess file which i'm using to remove the index.php from the URL?

This is what I have in there:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

    # Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Please ask one question per posting.  The 503 and slowness are unrelated.

Comment: 503 is the expected result when you have the site as "offline" in EE preferences.  There's nothing special that pingdom is seeing.  You can see yourself in Chrome Inspector that the page is being returned as 503.

Comment: For slowness consider turning on Output Profiler and or Template Debugging.  Slowness when there is no load is often due to database issues (unindexed queries etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I had that problem when the site was offline.  Can you try with the site online?

Comment: That's exactly what it was!